# Can't delete new or existing lines in StackBlitz

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, typescript, stackblitz

I wanted to try out React on StackBlitz. Unfortunately, I'm unable to delete any line of code.
Am I the only one who can insert new lines of code, but can't delete any of them?
I've tried logging in with GitHub, but did not solve the issue.
Here's the link to try out. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ppebr9?file=index.js
Couldn't find any useful information about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread is quite highly ranked for this search term so I will add some info I just found. The problem is well known and seem to have been for quite some time, seems related to the editor backend read more here: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/531

Quite sad for such a good looking product to be stuck this long without decent mobile support. It's advertised as a PWA which doesn't ring true when there's no way to use it on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the link, which is perfectly fine for me.
you can delete/edit/add, do whatever you want, it does not need to log in.
I am not sure if this is a code-related problem.